# postgresql on HP NonStop system

Tags: postgresql, hp-ux, hp-nonstop

I want to install postgres on HP NonStop J series server.
Can someone who is having experience on similar configuration help me out?
I did not found any postgres libraries/installation packages/patches for NonStop servers.

I am new to NonStop systems but have worked on linux and unix (HP-UX) environment.
NonStop systems provides Open System Services (OSS) environment which is an open computing interface to the HP NonStop operating system and is based on POSIX standards.

Postgres package is available for HP-UX system; can it be configured for OSS environment on Non Stop server ?

Comment: No idea, but your best bet is probably building postgresql from source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will almost certainly have to compile PostgreSQL - and possibly its dependencies, depending on what's available pre-packaged for HP-UX - from source code. See [installation from source code](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/installation.html) in the docs.

PostgreSQL is pretty well behaved and reasonable to compile, and there's a [HP-UX ia64 buildfarm member](http://buildfarm.postgresql.org/cgi-bin/show_history.pl?nm=anole&br=HEAD) so builds are tested on HP-UX.

Comment: I have downloaded the source code from postgres site, copied it to osh environment in tandem, but not able to untar it. Sometimes it shows permission problems and if I try to untar the file from super.super login then it shows error that tar this does not seem to be valid tar archive and skips all other files. (i.e. tar is partially extracted).       Is There any other way to extract the tar. I have used "tar -xvf" command to extract files from tar.

Comment: @Ashsh Use GNU tar. You'll also need to use gnu make ("gmake") to compile.